# how to use .contains to select certain letters of the alphabet

Tags: java, contains

I need the user input to: 
- have no numbers 
- be 4 characters long 
- only use certain letters of the alphabet [R, B, G, P, Y, O] 
I have figured out how to do no numbers and only 4 character length, however, I can't seem to figure out how to restrict certain letters of the alphabet (everything other than R, B, G, P, Y, O.)

```
        guess = input.nextLine();
        guess = guess.toUpperCase();
        while (guess.length() != 4 || guess.contains("[0-9]") || guess.contains("[ACDEFHIJKLMNQSTUVWXZ]")) {
            System.out.println("Bad input! Try again");
            System.out.println("Use the form \"BGRY\"");
            guess = input.nextLine();
        }
```

This is the code I have so far, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of string method `contains` - as found [here, for example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: `String::contains` doesn't take a regex. It just checks for the literal sequence given.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do it [as follows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)):

```
while(!guess.matches("[RBGPYO]{4}")) {
    // ...
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(matches("RBGPYO"));
        System.out.println(matches("RBGP"));
        System.out.println(matches("R1BGP"));
        System.out.println(matches("ABCD"));
        System.out.println(matches("1234"));
        System.out.println(matches("BGPY"));
        System.out.println(matches("BYPG"));
    }

    static boolean matches(String input) {
        return input.matches("[RBGPYO]{4}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
false
true
false
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: OP, for you, this would look like this: `if(input.matches("[RBGPYO]{4}")){do this}`

Comment: Given that they're trying to repeat on failure, it's more likely they want `while(!guess.matches("[RBGPYO]{4}")){ failure stuff }`.

Answer (score 1):

**There are also a lot of ways without using Regex.**

You cannot use [`String::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) in this case since this method works with a certain character sequence and your use-case is too specific. However, you can use the advantage of [`List::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) which might be more useful as long as the `String` is be understood as a `List<Character>` using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream):

```
List<Integer> characters = "RBGPYO".chars()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

boolean matches = guess.length() == 4 && 
    guess.toUpperCase().chars().allMatch(characters::contains);
```

If you are not a fan of this feature, a good old way for-loop:

```
List<Character> characters = Arrays.asList('R', 'B', 'G', 'P', 'Y', 'O');
boolean matches = guess.length() == 4;
if (matches) {
    for (char ch : guess.toUpperCase().toCharArray()) {
        if (!characters.contains(ch)) {
            matches = false;             
            break;                         // it's important to break the cycle
        }
    }
}
```

---

In any case, important is to **check the length before you check the characters**. This is valid as long as the `guess` should contain characters and to be of a *certain* length.